# How to install debian on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: debian

i installed ubuntu 14.04 in my laptop and tried to install debian on ubuntu 14.04 but could not istall that is why please anyone help me **How to install debian on ubuntu 14.04**

Answer (score 2):

Debian is an Operating System, like Ubuntu. You can't install Debian on Ubuntu. Ubuntu is a distribution of Debian. If you're wanting to replace Ubuntu with Debian, download the Debian ISO, create a bootable device with the ISO, and then install it, replacing Ubuntu.